# looping through bitmap pixels to change color of a bitmap in android

Tags: android, bitmap

I am trying to change the color of a bitmap based on a hex value.

before i attempt to us myBitmap.setPixel with the color chosen in my color picker, im just trying to get it working with an rgb like so:

```
    for (int x = 0; x <= myBitmap.getWidth(); x++) {

            for (int y = 0; x <= myBitmap.getHeight(); y++) {

                myBitmap.setPixel(x, y, Color.rgb(255, 255, 255));

            }

        }
```

if I set just one pixel like so:

```
    bitmapPreview.setPixel(50, 50, Color.rgb(255, 255, 255));
```

it works just fine, but when i attempt to loop through the bitmap pixels it force closes the application

any suggestion on how to make this work, or another recommendation on how i can change the color of a bitmap based on a value returned from a color chooser.  the format of the value returned from the color chooser is this : white = -1 or a blue shade = -15658590

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason behind application force close is you are performing CPU intensive operation.
your long running operation should be always performed in AsyncTask and not on UI thread of application.

**Option 1:**

create a Sub class of AsyncTask<> class and do your pixel operation in doInBackground method. that will not force close the application

**Option 2 : (Better choice for Bitmap operation )**

use RenderScript for performing such graphic operation. RenderScript is cross platform and can perform pixel operation faster than looping in java code.

Comment: thank you very much! i will try your recommendations!

Answer (score 7):

If this is the exact code you are using, your loop conditions are wrong. You are exceeding the limits of the bitmap by 1 pixel in both dimensions, and you have used the wrong variable to check one of the dimensions. Change `<=` to `<` in both loops, and change `x` in the second for condition to `y`:

```
for (int x = 0; x < myBitmap.getWidth(); x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < myBitmap.getHeight(); y++) {
        myBitmap.setPixel(x, y, Color.rgb(255, 255, 255));
    }
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. If it resolved your problems, you can accept the answer. If not, please post the logcat with the error message and I'll try again.

Comment: actually i used your fixes in an async task so both of you helped me a lot! how do i accept both? lol

Comment: To be honest, one pass through a bitmap with no real computation shouldn't kill the app. The AsyncTask isn't a bad idea, but it wasn't your problem. The answer you accept is up to you, though.